# Samsung Galaxy III screen turning on by itself and draining battery

Tags: battery, screen, samsung-galaxy-apollo

Even though I haven't received any notifications, the screen on my Samsung Galaxy III keeps turning on and draining my battery. What's causing this?

Comment: I'd guess some app. Anything you recently installed before this issue came up?

Comment: Izzy is right, uninstall any software which you installed after the last time your phone was OK, and check if it turns on automatically again.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm afraid it's a hardware issue.